# Find if the string (sentence) in a list of string in other columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if sentence columns contains any keyword in other columns (without case sensitive).

I also got the problem when import file from csv, the keyword list has ' ' on the string so when I tried to use join str.join('|') it add | into every character

```
Sentence = ["Clear is very good","Fill- low light, compact","stripping topsoil"]
Keyword =[['Clearing', 'grubbing','clear','grub'],['Borrow,', 'Fill', 'and', 'Compaction'],['Fall']]
 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence': Sentence, 'Keyword': Keyword})
```

My expect output will be
`df['Match'] = [True,True,False]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `DataFrame.apply` on rows

```py
import re
df['Match'] = df.apply(lambda row: bool(re.search('|'.join(row['Keyword']), row['Sentence'], re.IGNORECASE)), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

                   Sentence                            Keyword  Match
0        Clear is very good  [Clearing, grubbing, clear, grub]   True
1  Fill- low light, compact   [Borrow,, Fill, and, Compaction]   True
2         stripping topsoil                             [Fall]  False
```